# Adding php inside image src not working?

Tags: php

I know this has already been put out on here but I've looked and mine still won't work and I don't know why someone please give me a hand.

```
 echo '<img src="' . Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(50,50); . '"/>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon you have after resize

```
 echo '<img src="' . Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(50,50) . '"/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo "<img src= '".Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(50,50)."'/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
echo '<img src="' . Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(50,50); . '"/>';
```

this line to

```
 echo '<img src="' . Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(50,50) . '"/>';
```

Because you had put one extra semi column `;` after the `resize(50,50)`

Please change your code and try. Definitely work .